# Which VMWare client for hosting Ubuntu in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I have not booted up a virtual machine in aeons.

I am currently downloading the `ruby on rails` `ubuntu` stack from Bitnami.

I went over to `VMWare` and was overwhelmed by the amount of software titles they have.

Question, for Windows 7 Ultimate, which is the best VM client to host the ubuntu stack?

Ideally it's free. If it's not can you point out what I'd me missing by not buying the full fat version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are two I personally have used. Which one you use depends on what you want. Both should meet the job you are looking for here. If you want to go the VMWare route you can use their free application called VMWare Player, which you can get  [here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0)

If you want to try another there is also Virtual Box from Oracle, which is also free. You can get this one from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

I have hosted Ubuntu on Windows using both these applications. I have had better success with VMWare Player using an Ubuntu host, but this probably isn't relevant to you.

I could post reviews on which is better, but its all a matter of opinion. I suggest starting with VMWare Player and read a couple reviews.

Comment: OK thanks. I had found VMWare Player Plus but was scared off by it's "buy online" button..I will give it a whirl.